# CSS reverse morphing animation on hover

Tags: css, css-animations

i have circle element animating on my page, what i try to do is to smoothly transition it on hover, to be just a square with it original size: 200px x 200px. And also, on mouse leave to smoothly back to previous (morphing) state. Any ideas? Heres my code:

```css
a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30% 70% 70% 30% / 30% 30% 70% 70%;
  animation: morphing ease-in-out 10s infinite;
}

a:hover {

}

@keyframes morphing {
  0% {
    border-radius: 30% 70% 70% 30% / 30% 30% 70% 70%;
  }
  25% {
    border-radius: 58% 42% 75% 25% / 76% 46% 54% 24%;
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 33% 67% / 55% 27% 73% 45%;
  }
  75% {
    border-radius: 33% 67% 58% 42% / 63% 68% 32% 37%;
  }
}
```

```html
<a>sample text</a>
```

Comment: Mind if I use some JavaScript for this?

Comment: @TechySharnav sure

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so here it goes. On `mouseover`, we start the morphing animation. On `mouseout`, we set the border radius to start position.

You can play with duration (which is in milliseconds) as per your liking.

```js
let elem = document.querySelector("a");
let morphAnim = elem.getAnimations()[0];

elem.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
  elem.animate(morphAnim.effect.getKeyframes(), {
    easing: "ease-in-out",
    duration: 10000,
    iterations: Infinity,
    iterationStart: 0.1
  })
})


elem.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
  elem.animate({
    borderRadius: "30% 70% 70% 30% / 30% 30% 70% 70%"
  }, {
    duration: 1000,
    fill: "forwards",
    iterations: 1
  });

})
```

```css
a {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 30% 70% 70% 30% / 30% 30% 70% 70%;
  animation: morphing ease-in-out 10s infinite;
  animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes morphing {
  0% {
    border-radius: 30% 70% 70% 30% / 30% 30% 70% 70%;
  }
  25% {
    border-radius: 58% 42% 75% 25% / 76% 46% 54% 24%;
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 33% 67% / 55% 27% 73% 45%;
  }
  75% {
    border-radius: 33% 67% 58% 42% / 63% 68% 32% 37%;
  }
}
```

```html
<a>sample text</a>
```

Comment: i hoped it's posiible within css only, but i guess it's not, great solution, BTW, is there simple way to use it for multiple elements eg. with te same class instead of "a"?

Comment: already figured it out BTW, thanks

Comment: @Marek Welcome. Unfortunately, there is no way to achieve it using CSS. That's why I had to resort to JS.

Comment: can you please modify this a little, to start morphing animation on hover, and get back to start position on mouse leave? We can ignore setting border radius to 0%. Those javascript animations gives me a headache

Comment: @Marek Please check the updated answer.